# MVC 2 RegularExpression for a single letter is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a Regular Expression Validation for a Single Capital Letter, but it does not work.
When I put in a valid letter, I get the error message;

```
        [DisplayName("Contract Letter")]
        [RegularExpression("[A-Z]", ErrorMessage = "Must be a letter")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Letter is required")]
        public string ContractNo_Letter { get; set; }
```

I am only allowing the input of 1 letter.

Comment: Have you traced into the controller action to confirm that the field name being retrieved is correct and that the letter is actually getting returned to your object?

Comment: are other validations working?

Comment: Other validations are working, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to consider here:

- The regular expression you have specified will evaluate to true provided that there is at least one letter from A-Z anywhere within the expression. For example: `8979*(&#$HJ` will evaluate to true. To match exactly one letter, you can wrap your regex with the special characters: `^` (start of line), and `$` (end of string).
- Regular expressions in DataAnnotations are case-sensitive. To check both upper and lower-case letters, use `[A-Za-z]`.

So, to match a single letter without case sensitivity, use `^[A-Za-z]$`.

Comment: I have edited my question to make clear I am only checking a single character that must be a capital letter.

Comment: OK I found the problem. I was using CSS to enforce uppercase letters, see 
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.contract.ContractNo_Letter, 
                            new { maxlength = "1", style = "width:15px;text-transform: uppercase;" })%>

However although visually this converts the letter on the screen, it doesn't do so in the underlying model. So [A-Za-z] is the correct answer. I will just have to make sure I have a setter on my field that converts the character to upper case when I save it.

Comment: Personally, I'd still check the start and end on the regex. Your client currently prevents you from entering more than one character, but you shouldn't be relying solely on client-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your regex to:

```
"[A-Za-z]"
```